# GoogleAnalytics - Group events by users

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I used the Google's developer guide's example to create an event for my Android app to see it in my Google Analytics account:

```
// Get tracker.
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
    TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
// Build and send an Event.
t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
    .setCategory(getString(categoryId))
    .setAction(getString(actionId))
    .setLabel(getString(labelId))
    .build());
```

The problem is that all the events are shown togather. Is there a way to somehow group them by users so I can see how many events happened per user and not just how many happened in total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to be able to track event completions per session, then you can simply use your event in conjunction with [goals](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en) (goals are only counted once per session). However, if you require counting events per user than you will probably have to use the [User ID custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id).

Comment: What's the difference? Isn't a session is of a single user? meaning if I track events per session then won't I also get automatically events per user?

Comment: @YonatanNir No. A single user can participate in multiple sessions. GA has a very specific default definition for session (and it's not very intuitive). Probably worth checking out: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en

Comment: Do you might have a link for the user id custom dimension for an Android app instead of a website?

Comment: @YonatanNir https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/user-id

Comment: I've added custom dimensions and metrices.. where do I see their values? I don't see anything in the reporting tab.

Comment: @YonatanNir GA can take a day or more to refresh. You'll have to wait a little while, but then you can find custom dimensions & metrics in custom reports, advanced segments, and as secondary dimensions in standard reports.

Comment: I don't see any option called "custom reports" nor "secondary dimensions" in the left pane of the reporting tab. I'd expected to find it under the "Events" option under the Real time or Behavior option but nothing was there.

Comment: Do you want to try another question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238802/google-analytics-dimensions-and-metrices-update

Answer (score 0):

The way you need to do it is by creating a custom dimension (which is like a table's primary key which is for example a user id) and a custom metric (which is like a regular column in a table) and then you can make a custom report or a dashboard containing these dimensions and metrices.

This is a guide how to create them:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en